# New account suspension

Tags: support, account-suspension

I created an account on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) today.
Subsequently it said, you get 100 bonus reputation points since you are on other networks.
But my reputation points still shows as 1.

On the accounts page it shows:

> This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends on Aug 4, 2024 at 6:24.

1. What rule violations did I do?
2. Why suspension on a new account?

Comment: This means you have deleted your previously suspended account on that site. At least, that's what the system thinks, and it's usually correct. Deleting account while it is suspended does not clear the suspension, SE isn't *that* stupid. In case you really wasn't suspended before, click the "contact" link in the footer, and send a request to check it.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/anti-recidivism-system/info "We log data on such accounts at time of deletion, which is then referenced should a new account from the same individual be created. If the user was suspended at the time of deletion, then the new account will inherit the remainder of the original suspension..."

Comment: "What rule violations did I do?" My best guess, given that "The suspension period ends on Aug 4, 2024 at 6:24.", is: the ones that you were explicitly messaged about on or around Aug 4, *this year*, perhaps at or near 6:24. "Why suspension on a new account?" My best guess is that your rule violations occurred on a *different* account, which makes this one ban evasion which is automatically and inherently punishable.

Comment: Well yes. I suppose the question is *should that be more obvious in some way?*. There's no moderator message initially though -when an answer is destroyed so OP *is* right to be confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't discuss suspensions in public — a previous account was *destroyed* and there's an automatic one year suspension for that.

We'll send a moderator message explaining what happened instead, and what you should do, in a fair bit of detail.

In *this* case, we do recommend using the contact us link — linking back here, asking them to review the suspension.